# Не могу настроить 301 редирект в битрикс 1 с

Tags: php, битрикс

Никак не могу настроить 301 редирект в битрикс 1с. Пишу в htacces:

```
 Redirect 301 /index.php https://tagil-steel.ru/
```

Выходит ошибка ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. В чем может быть проблема? Буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема описана в ошибки. Слишком много перенаправлений. Т.е. вы делаете редирект с /index.php на сайт.

Но похоже что вы редактируете .htaccess для этого самого сайта.

Т.е. браузер перенаправляется на тот же самый сайт - он попадает на index.php и дальше опять срабатывает правило и браузер опять перенаправляется на сайт. И так по кругу. И в какой-то момент бразуер выдает ошибку.

Не очень понятно что именно вы пытаетесь сделать. Возможно у вас цель, чтобы был редирект на HTTPS версию. Но в этом случае надо добавлять условие, чтобы редирект срабатывал только в том случае, если открывается HTTP версия.

Например, вот так

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
Redirect 301 /index.php https://tagil-steel.ru/
```

Comment: Спасибо, что ответили. Мне нужно сделать редирект с https://tagil-steel.ru/index.php на https://tagil-steel.ru/.   Такое возможно сделать или в любом случае будет повторяться эта ошибка?

Comment: @Pavel очень странная идея. Похоже на какое-то SEO мракобесие.